# If I got the answer in my question during on chat how to indicate to others?

Tags: discussion

to all If I get the answer in the chat room of the Salesforce in stack exchange then How I noticed to others to I get the answer for this question like best answer?

Comment: I think you would have to get the person that supplied the answer in chat to post it as an answer to the question and then mark it as accepted as normal.

Comment: @DaveHumm Thanks for the reply I am a new bee in the chat that's why I ask this question.

Comment: @DaveHumm that'd make a good answer here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chat does not allow you to mark a response as an answer, it is best to say to the person that has provided that answer to post it as an answer to the original question and then accept that answer.

Comment: I would just add that if you have tried to get this person to post their solution as an answer and a long time elapses without (say, a week), you should just post what the solution was and credit who laid it out for you.